# Populating data in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I have following jqgrid table(contains only multi-level headers).

[Table looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bA5h2.png)

For multilevel header, I have used following trick:

```
                    grid.jqGrid("setGroupHeaders", {
                        useColSpanStyle: true,
                        groupHeaders: [{
                            startColumnName: "amount",
                            numberOfColumns: 5,
                            titleText:
                                '<table style="width:100%;border-spacing:0px;">' +
                                '<tr><td id="h0" colspan="2"><em>Details</em></td></tr>' +
                                '<tr>' +
                                    '<td id="h1">...</td>' +
                                    '<td id="h2">...</td>' +
                                '</tr>' +
                                '</table>'
                        }]
                    });
```

Now, the data I want to populate looks like:

```
                    {
                        "Date_2015-01-01_Total Sales": 1,
                        "Date_2015-01-02_Total Sales": 0,
                        "id": 1,
                        "timekey": "09:15"
                    },
                    {
                        "Date_2015-01-01_Total Sales": 1,
                        "Date_2015-01-02_Total Sales": 7,
                        "id": 2,
                        "timekey": "10:00"
                    }
```

How can I populate this data in the table.

Comment: Which version of jqGrid and from which fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7) you use? [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/pivotGroupingCustomAggregate.htm) uses free jqGrid and it calls `setGroupHeaders` *multiple times*. The demo uses `jqPivot`, but one can call `setGroupHeaders` multiple times in your custom code too.

Comment: Thanks for the response.Where can I find demo for multilevel header( at most three) which does not use jqPivot.